# DoCmd.RunSQL CREATE TABLE statement with DEFAULT values using vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using VBA in ms Access to run an SQL statement. When I try to run it, it always shows "Syntax error in create table statement". Can you spot my mistake? I have been trying now for over 3 hours...

```
Private Sub Btn_create report_Click()


Dim SQL_2 As String

SQL_2 ="CREATE TABLE TR_Customer_data" & _
"[Field 1] CHAR(30) DEFAULT '1'" & _
"[Field 2] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'MCR'" & _
"[Field 3] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'GE34567'" & _
"[Field 4] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'apple and bananas'" & _
"[Field 5] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 6] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 7] CHAR(30) DEFAULT '192.0.0.1'" & _
"[Field 8] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 9] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 10] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 11] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'CPR'" & _
"[Field 12] CHAR(30) DEFAULT '7.0'" & _
"[Field 13] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 14] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 15] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 16] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 17] CHAR(30)" & _
"[Field 18] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'John.Doe@gmail.com'" & _
"[Field 19] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'John.Doe@gmail.com'" & _
"[Field 20] CHAR(30) DEFAULT 'town/city'" & _
"[Field 21] CHAR(30)"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_2`
End Sub
```

Can you help me spot my mistake?

Comment: You need a comma between each column definition.

Comment: Also, don't forget spaces. You don't have spaces or linebreaks between fields. Replace `& _` with `& vbCrLf & _` to insert a break in the string too.

Comment: `"[Field 13], CHAR(30)" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 14], CHAR(30)" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 15], CHAR(30)" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 16], CHAR(30)" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 17], CHAR(30)" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 18], CHAR(30), DEFAULT 'max.muster@gmail.com'" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 19], CHAR(30), DEFAULT 'max.muster@gmail.com'" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 20], CHAR(30), DEFAULT 'town/city'" & vbCrLf & _

"[Field 21], CHAR(30)"`

Like this?

Comment: Spaces are critical so text doesn't 'run together' when string compiles, however, I have never used vbCrLf to construct SQL statement. For correct syntax review https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-create/

Comment: Also missing parentheses around fields array list. Access doesn't seem to recognize DEFAULT keyword. SQL errors when I include. This link shows syntax with DEFAULT https://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-default-constraint/

Comment: If Access does not acknowledge DEFAULT keyword, likely need DAO TableDefs to modify table object. Why do you need to implement a procedure that routinely creates table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid Access DDL `CREATE TABLE` statement should have a comma-separated list of field definitions enclosed within a pair of parentheses following the table name.  The statement built by the code in your question lacks both the commas and the enclosing parentheses.

Here is a valid statement which I tested in Access 2010:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TR_Customer_data ([Field 1] CHAR(30) DEFAULT "1",[Field 2] CHAR(30) DEFAULT "MCR")
```

I used this VBA to build and execute that statement:

```vb
Dim SQL_2 As String

SQL_2 = "CREATE TABLE TR_Customer_data (" & _
    "[Field 1] CHAR(30) DEFAULT ""1""," & _
    "[Field 2] CHAR(30) DEFAULT ""MCR"")"
Debug.Print SQL_2

'DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_2 '<- No! Will not support `DEFAULT` keyword
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute SQL_2
```

Notes:

- `DEFAULT` is not supported by `DoCmd.RunSQL` ... it will always give you that error 3290, *"Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement."*  Execute the statement from `CurrentProject.Connection` or via another method based on OleDb.
- Use double quotes surrounding the default values in your DDL statement text.  If you use single quotes instead, they will be included as part of the default value.  And when building the statement in VBA, use 2 double quotes where you want 1 within the completed statement.